# Automatic Functor Instance

Tags: haskell

Given the following algebraic type:

```
ghci> data Foo a = Foo a
```

Then I instantiate one of them.

```
ghci> let f = Foo "foo"
```

Lastly, I'd like to call `fmap` to apply a function as, `(a -> b) -> Foo a -> Foo b`.

```
ghci> fmap (++ "bar") f

<interactive>:78:1:
    No instance for (Functor Foo) arising from a use of ‘fmap’
    In the expression: fmap (++ "bar") f
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = fmap (++ "bar") f
```

But, since I didn't implement a `Functor` instance of `Foo`, I can't use `fmap`.

Is there a way to get `Functor` instances for free? I have zero knowledge of Haskell's compiler, but perhaps it's clever enough to know that `fmap` on `Foo a` is simply apply `(a -> b)` to `Foo`'s `a`?

Comment: The  problem with derived functor instances is they might not work in the way you expect. When in doubt, write it yourself!

Comment: @AJFarmar At least extensionally and avoiding undefined, parametricity guarantees that there is most one fmap. Performancewise, of course, some corners may remain uncut by the automatics.

Comment: @pigworker's comment boils down (well, waters down, actually) to this: Under normal circumstances (for a specific value of "normal"), there is only *one* valid instance `Functor T` for any given `T`, and `DeriveFunctor` will produce that instance. Writing the instances by hand is an excellent way to understand them, though. I've learned a lot by studying the hand-written instances in `base`, `free`, `folds`, and many other libraries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Working in ghci, if you make the incantation

```
Prelude> :set -XDeriveFunctor
```

then the compiler will become as clever as you are hoping for, if not quite as enthusiastic. You will need to invoke the functionality, thus,

```
Prelude> data Foo a = Foo a deriving (Show, Functor)
```

(the `Show` is just for printing the output, below) and then you will be able to do stuff like

```
Prelude> fmap (++"bar") (Foo "foo")
Foo "foobar"
```

In a module, you achieve the same by adding the pragma

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
```

before the `module` declaration. It's good for at least the more straightforward `Functor` instances, but you can fool it into a false negative.

```
Prelude> data Boo a = Boo (Either a Bool) deriving Functor

<interactive>:9:43:
    Can't make a derived instance of ‘Functor Boo’:
      Constructor ‘Boo’ must use the type variable only as the
        last argument of a data type
      In the data declaration for ‘Boo’
```

Meanwhile

```
data Goo a = Goo (Either Bool a) deriving Functor
```

is ok, and the machinery has clearly been hacked to work with pairing, as

```
data Woo a = Woo (a, Bool) deriving Functor
```

is permitted.

So it's not as clever as it could be, but it's better than a poke in the eye.

Comment: I've noticed that `Either` case before (hm, wasn't it in one of your other answers?), it seems to me that for such things to work properly, GHC would need to learn about bi- and more generally multi-functors.

Answer (score 4):

Sure it can, add `deriving Functor` to your data declaration and `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}` at the top of file.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, is using this compiler directive considered good, bad, or simply style?

Comment: Using it means that you are using compiler-specific extension. So, in theory, this makes your code less portable.

Comment: @KevinMeredith, the "in theory" is because at the present time there's only one practically relevant Haskell implementation; it also seems fairly likely that a future practically relevant implementation would also support `DeriveFunctor`—it's proven itself sufficiently useful and sufficiently well-behaved.