# Is (\f -> fmap f id) always equivalent to arr?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory, arrows, category-abstractions

Some instances of `Category` are also instances of `Functor`. For example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, TupleSections #-}

import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
import Control.Category
import Control.Arrow

data State a b = forall s. State (s -> a -> (s, b)) s

apply :: State a b -> a -> b
apply (State f s) = snd . f s

assoc :: (a, (b, c)) -> ((a, b), c)
assoc (a, (b, c)) = ((a, b), c)

instance Category State where
    id = State (,) ()
    State g t . State f s = State (\(s, t) -> assoc . fmap (g t) . f s) (s, t)

(.:) :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
(.:) = fmap . fmap

instance Functor (State a) where
    fmap g (State f s) = State (fmap g .: f) s

instance Arrow State where
    arr f = fmap f id
    first (State f s) = State (\s (x, y) -> fmap (,y) (f s x)) s
```

Here `arr f = fmap f id` for `instance Arrow State`. Is this true for all instances of `Category` which are also instances of `Functor`? The type signatures are:

```
arr               ::                 Arrow    a  => (b -> c) -> a b c
(\f -> fmap f id) :: (Functor (a t), Category a) => (b -> c) -> a b c
```

It seems to me that they should be equivalent.

Comment: At the very least, the `Arrow` laws are enough to *define* a law-abiding `Functor` instance by `instance Arrow a => Functor (a s) where fmap f v = v >>> arr f`. Perhaps that together with parametricity is enough to ensure that this is also the *only* law-abiding instance, though I haven't worked out the details so I won't claim it to be true.

Comment: Remember that, for functions and arrows, `fmap` should equal `(<<<)`.

Comment: [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395214/automatic-functor-instance#comment45136634_28395214) suggests that I was correct: parametricity guarantees at most one law-abiding `Functor` instance. So the answer to your question seems to be "yes".

Comment: Since `arr` is a method of `Arrow`, not `Category`, I am still somewhat skeptical - I doubt every `Category` that also is a `Functor` needs to be an `Arrow`. The reverse is true, however, as every `Arrow` [gives not just a `Functor`, but an `Applicative`](https://cdsmith.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/arrow-category-applicative-part-i/).

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen "I doubt every `Category` that also is a `Functor` needs to be an `Arrow`" - indeed, though the underlying issue is that `arr` and `first` are, as leftaroundabout says below, "quite separate things combined".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let's be clear what `Arrow C` means. Well, it's two quite separate things combined – in my book,

- The class of [well-pointed monoidal categories](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:WellPointed).
- The class of [categories which generalise **Hask**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:EnhancedCat).

`arr` comes from the latter. “Generalise” **Hask**? What this means is just to have a mapping from the category **Hask** to `C`. – And mathematically, mapping from one category to another is exactly what a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) does! (The standard `Functor` class actually covers only a very specific sort of functors, namely endofunctors on **Hask**.) `arr` is the morphism-aspect of a non-endofunctor, namely the “canonical embedding functor” **Hask** → `C`.

From this point of view, the first two arrow laws

```
arr id = id
arr (f >>> g) = arr f >>> arr g
```

are just the functor laws.

Now, what does it mean if you're implementing a `Functor` instance for a category? Why, I daresay it simply means you're expressing that same canonical embedding functor, but via the necessary representation of `C` back in **Hask** (which makes it an endofunctor overall). Hence I'd argue that yes, `\f -> fmap f id` should be equivalent to `arr`, since basically they're two ways of expressing the same thing.

Comment: @duplode: actually not. I posted the wrong link (`Function` does the opposite thing, it's the class of specialised, rather than generalised functions). This is how it would be correct: “In terms of `constrained-categories`, every `Category C` which is also a `Functor C (->) (->)` is an `EnhancedCat C (->)` as well”.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a derivation to supplement leftaroundabout's explanation. For clarity, I will reserve `(.)` and `id` for `(->)`, and use `(<<<)` and `id'` for the general `Category` methods.

We begin with `preComp`, also known as `(>>>)`:

```
preComp :: Category y => y a b -> (y b c -> y a c)
preComp v = \u -> u <<< v
```

`fmap` commutes with natural transformations between **Hask** endofunctors. For a `Category` which also has a `Functor` instance, `preComp v` is a natural transformation (from `y b` to `y a`), and so it commutes with `fmap`. It follows that:

```
fmap f . preComp v = preComp v . fmap f
fmap f (u <<< v) = fmap f u <<< v
fmap f (id' <<< v) = fmap f id' <<< v
fmap f v = fmap f id' <<< v
```

That's our candidate `arr`! So let's define `arr' f = fmap f id'`. We can now verify that `arr'` follows the first arrow law...

```
-- arr id = id'
arr' id
fmap id id'
id'
```

... and the second one too:

```
-- arr (g . f) = arr g <<< arr f
arr' (g . f)
fmap (g . f) id'
(fmap g . fmap f) id'
fmap g (fmap f id')
fmap g (arr' f)
fmap g id' <<< arr' f -- Using the earlier result.
arr' g <<< arr' f
```

I suppose that is as far as we can get. The other five arrow laws involve `first`, and as leftaroundabout points out `arr` and `first` are independent.